After pushing log out button the app is forwarding me to empty page
After pushing log out button the app is forwarding me to https://it-company-task-manager-uzrc.onrender.com/accounts/login/
But there is an empty page and after log out I'm still logged in and can do things (create task etc)
I tried to solve it in different ways, but nothing changes. You can check it by yourself: https://it-company-task-manager-uzrc.onrender.com
sidebar.html:
<li class="">
           <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="icon">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-right-from-bracket"></i>
              <span class="ml-4">Log out</span>
            </a>
          </li>

login.html:
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block login %}
  <section class="login-content">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center height-self-center">
         <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="card auth-card">
               <div class="card-body p-0">
                  <div class="d-flex align-items-center auth-content">
                     <div class="col-lg-6 bg-primary content-left">
                        <div class="p-3">
                           <h2 class="mb-2 text-white">Sign In</h2>
                           <p>Login to stay connected.</p>
                            {% if form.non_field_errors   %}
                              {{ form.non_field_errors   }}
                            {% endif %}
                           <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
                             {% csrf_token %}
                              <div class="row">
                                 <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="floating-label form-group">
                                        {% if form.username.errors %}
                                          {{ form.username.errors }}
                                        {% endif %}
                                       <input class="floating-input form-control" type="text"  name="username" placeholder="Username">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="floating-label form-group">
                                        {% if form.password.errors %}
                                          {{ form.password.errors }}
                                        {% endif %}
                                       <input class="floating-input form-control" type="password"  name="password" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}" />
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-white">Sign In</button>
                           </form>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-6 content-right">
                        <img src="{% static 'images/login/01.png' %}" class="img-fluid image-right" alt="">
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </section>
{% endblock %}


settings:
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/accounts/login/"

urls:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import RedirectView


urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path("", RedirectView.as_view(url="tasks/", permanent=True)),
    path("tasks/", include("task.urls", namespace="task")),
    path("employees/", include("employee.urls", namespace="employee"))
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


ok. Where is your views.py code? and <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="icon"> is wrong. shouldn't it be ``` ?

And where is your registration view? I couldn't find it.

You can check it here

Look at my answer and test it. If you get any problems after that, mention them here.

If you're using Django 5, it's possible you're running into the same issue that is addressed in these questions:

Django built in Logout view `Method Not Allowed (GET): /users/logout/`
Problem with Django class-based LogoutView in Django 5.0

Essentially, you can no longer access the built-in logout view with a GET request; you have to do it with a POST request.
So, like willeM_ Van Onsem suggests in the first link above, you need to wrap your logout button in a small form:
<form method="post" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">logout</button>
</form>

In my Django app, a POST request to the Django-standard '/logout' endpoint will log the user out and redirect to a 'logged_out.html' template that you might already have with the rest of your registration templates (or you might be using the one that already comes with Django).

1) Try this.

path("", RedirectView.as_view(url="/tasks", permanent=True)),

2) And,
<a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="icon">

is wrong.
Shouldn't it be
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="icon">


Not working. :(

Ok. Then, set debug true in your local environment and post the error message here.
